# how to remove “&” being replaced by "&amp; in php include

Tags: php, json

```
$merchantRefNumber = $payment[ID];
$signature = $merchantCode.$merchantRefNumber.$secureKey;
$signature = hash('sha256', $signature);
$URL = ("https://www.atfawry.com/ECommerceWeb/Fawry/payments/status?merchantCode=".($merchantCode)."&merchantRefNumber=".($merchantRefNumber)."&signature=".($signature));

$response =  file_get_contents($URL);
if ( $response )
{
```

this is the link it show from this code

```
https://www.atfawry.com/ECommerceWeb/Fawry/payments/status?merchantCode=CB8Q95Jr&amp;merchantRefNumber=AGHUY&amp;signature=135bfd157a9ac13931b512120609dc31ff31879
```

and it is should be show without `amp;` to be

```
https://www.atfawry.com/ECommerceWeb/Fawry/payments/status?merchantCode=CB8Q95Jr&merchantRefNumber=AGHUY&signature=135bfd157a9ac13931b512120609dc31ff31879
```

Comment: I don't see anything in your code that shows `&amp;`. That would be created if you used `htmlentities()` or `htmlspecialchars()`.

Comment: That's not coming from the code you posted.

Comment: thank you Barmar ,, it show &amp; really don't know from where i have to remove this

Comment: if i use $response = html_entity_decode($URL) instead of $response =  file_get_contents($URL); this is will work ?

Comment: GIve it a try and see. But since the code isn't adding `&amp;` in the first place, I'm not sure it will work.

Comment: or i have to change " to be '   $merchantCode)."&merchantRefNumber=".($merchantRefNumber)."&signature=".

Comment: "_this is the link it show from this code_" This code doesn't show anything. Where/how do you output that url?

Comment: "https://www.atfawry.com/ECommerceWeb/Fawry/payments/status?merchantCode=".($merchantCode)."&merchantRefNumber=".($merchantRefNumber)."&signature=".($signature));

when i remove & from "&merchantRefNumber="  , "&signature="  link is correct but it have to be there & in the link not  &amp

Comment: how to add url = Replace(url, "&amp;", "&") in this code ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `http_build_query`:

```
$url = "https://www.atfawry.com/ECommerceWeb/Fawry/payments/status";
$data = array(
    'merchantCode' => $merchantCode,
    'merchantRefNumber' => $merchantRefNumber,
    'signature' => $signature
);

$response = file_get_contents($url . "?" . http_build_query($data));
```

See also: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php

Comment: no i didn't work it give is result
https://www.atfawry.com/ECommerceWeb/Fawry/payments/status?merchantCode=CB8QbvJ5JrA%3D%3D&amp;merchantRefNumber=AGHDU&amp;signature=99176c90cbfcc8a75023e862d

Comment: If you want it with **$amp;** then use it like this: `$url . "?" . http_build_query($data, '', '&amp;')`

Comment: need without $amp

Comment: This gives you without **$amp;** `$url . "?" . http_build_query($data)`

Comment: this is as it was before and still give $amp

Comment: Please read Example #1 here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php

Comment: how to add this in the code url = Replace(url, "&amp;", "&")